# Add unique items to a listbox in Excel-VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently writing a VBA code for a file containing quite a large amount of data listed in a table, some of which are repeating.

I would like to populate a listbox in a userform so as I only get unique data values.

Below is the code I have written to do this:

```
'Year listbox population
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")

LastNonEmptyRow = .Range("C1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To LastNonEmptyRow
    For j = 0 To BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.ListCount
        If .Cells(i, 3) <> BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.List(j) Then BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.AddItem .Cells(i, 3)
    Next
Next

End With
```

I don't get any error prompt when I run the code above, but the listbox doesn't get populated despite the fact there is data in the Data sheet.

Would love some wits on this.

Thanks, and sorry if the question has already been asked in another post.

Answer (score 1):

Approach below wses a Dictionary and a Variant arry (rather than a range) for speed:

```
Sub Recut()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x
Dim objDic As Object
Dim lngCnt As Long

Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data")
x = ws.Range(ws.[c1], ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp)).Value2

For lngCnt = 1 To UBound(x)
    If Not objDic.exists(x(lngCnt, 1)) Then
        If Len(objDic.exists(x(lngCnt, 1))) > 0 Then
        objDic.Add x(lngCnt, 1), 1
        'add to your userform here
        End If
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few logical errors in your code.

1. Your `If` statement inside the list loop is not sufficient as it will add the item for each item that is different, which doesn't make any sense. To handle it I added a Boolean variable to state that at least one item is identical `doAdd = False`, and therefore the item should not be added.
2. If your list is empty to begin with, `BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.ListCount = 0`. The second loop runs once, and `BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.List(j)` is null. A null statement cannot be evaluated to a Boolean statement, only by using the `IsNull()` function, so you have to avoid nulls in your Boolean `If` statement.
3. Your second loop was set to run `For j = 0 To BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.ListCount` which is an incorrect count. You need to make it `BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.ListCount - 1`. This will also avoid the null scenario.

You need to do something like this:

```
Dim doAdd As Boolean
For i = 2 To LastNonEmptyRow
    doAdd = True
    For j = 0 To BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.ListCount - 1
        If .Cells(i, 3) = BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.List(j) Then
            doAdd = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If doAdd Then BudgetEdit.SelectedYear.AddItem .Cells(i, 3)
Next
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your input. I understand how your code is supposed to work, as the selectedyear population logic is the same as mine. I've implemented your code but the doAdd trick doesn't seem to work: my listbox gets populated with every item in the column (thousands of "2015" and "2016").
I'm trying another method using Excel's "remove duplicates" function, and I'll keep you posted.

Thanks again!

Comment: You can create a unique list in Excel instead, but this code should work. If you post your adjusted code I'll see what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

@depatinkin

I've found another solution using collections which works just fine:

```
Dim i, LastNonEmptyRow as integer
Dim Cell As Range
Dim Unique As New Collection
Dim Item As Range

LastNonEmptyRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Row

On Error Resume Next
For Each Cell In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("B2:B" & LastNonEmptyRow)
    Unique.Add Cell, Cstr(Cell)
NextCell
On Error GoTo 0

For Each Item In Unique
   .SelectedDate.AddItem Item
Next Item
```

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Can I ask how did you fix the type mismatch error when using this method please? I encountered this error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I found neat solution (forgot the source):

```
Sub addIfUnique(CB As ComboBox, Mystr As String)
'v 2.0 2020-03-03 ignore blanks
If Mystr = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    If CB.ListCount = 0 Then GoTo doAdd
    Dim i As Integer
    'MsgBox (MyStr)
    For i = 0 To CB.ListCount - 1
        If LCase(CB.List(i)) = LCase(Mystr) Then Exit Sub
    Next
doAdd:
    CB.AddItem Mystr
End Sub
```

And you call for it using something like this:

```
    Me.ComboBox4.Clear
    Dim Mystr As String
    i = 2
    Do Until SProducts.Cells(i, 4).Value = ""
      Mystr = CStr(SProducts.Cells(i, 4).Value)
      If SProducts.Cells(i, 6).Value = Me.ComboBox0.Value Then
          addIfUnique Me.ComboBox4, Mystr
      End If
      If Me.ComboBox0.Value = vbNullString Then addIfUnique Me.ComboBox4, Mystr 'all machines 2019-01-07
      
      i = i + 1
   Loop
```