# prevent duplication from list box

Tags: excel, vba

i have a userform which contaning search combobox for only data validation cells gives me results in lisbox but with all results from data validation

i want to get results with no duplicated values

the image shows duplicated values

```
the code used is
```

```
 Sub Refresh_List()

Dim arr() As String
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
Dim dict

Dim i As Integer
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Me.ListBox1.Clear

If Is_validation(ActiveCell) Then

    If Validate_Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1) Then
       Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1)
       
       For Each cel In rng
            If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
                Me.ListBox1.AddItem cel.Value
            Else
                If VBA.InStr(UCase(cel.Value), UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)) > 0 Then
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem cel.Value
                End If
            End If
       Next
    Else
    
    arr() = VBA.Split(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, ",")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If Me.TextBox1.Value = "" Then
                Me.ListBox1.AddItem arr(i)
            Else
                If VBA.InStr(UCase(arr(i)), UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)) > 0 Then
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem arr(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End If

End If


On Error Resume Next
Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
```

thnx in advance

image for duplication in listbox

[image: 1]

Comment: You may have a look onto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30048888/17172829 (maybe therefore you have already a dictionary in your code)

Comment: I am not expert in vba i got this code after long time i tried to add dictionary but couldn't continue to get it work,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.comP/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Refresh_List()
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dict, sKey
    Dim i As Integer
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    If Is_validation(ActiveCell) Then
        If Validate_Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1) Then
            Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1)
            For Each cel In rng
                sKey = cel.Value
                If Not dict.exists(sKey) Then
                    dict(sKey) = ""
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem sKey
                End If
            Next
        Else
            arr() = VBA.Split(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, ",")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                sKey = arr(i)
                If Not dict.exists(sKey) Then
                    dict(sKey) = ""
                    Me.ListBox1.AddItem sKey
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

---

***Update:***

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub Refresh_List2()
    Dim arr() As String
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cel As Range
    Dim dict, sKey, sTxt
    Dim i As Integer
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Me.ListBox1.Clear
    If Is_validation(ActiveCell) Then
        sTxt = UCase(Me.TextBox1.Value)
        If Validate_Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1) Then
            Set rng = Range(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1)
            For Each cel In rng
                sKey = cel.Value
                If VBA.InStr(UCase(sKey), sTxt) > 0 Or Len(sTxt) = 0 Then
                    If Not dict.exists(sKey) Then
                        dict(sKey) = ""
                        Me.ListBox1.AddItem sKey
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Else
            arr() = VBA.Split(ActiveCell.Validation.Formula1, ",")
            For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                sKey = arr(i)
                If VBA.InStr(UCase(sKey), sTxt) > 0 Or Len(sTxt) = 0 Then
                    If Not dict.exists(sKey) Then
                        dict(sKey) = ""
                        Me.ListBox1.AddItem sKey
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
        End If
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
    Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: I will give it try and tell you what happened, thnx in advance

Comment: it worked will, but the list don not update while typing it was updated with results for typed text so i can choose from

Comment: Do you typed in TextBox1? I've updated the code.

Comment: very smooth , thanx very much for your help

Comment: sry but another thing faced me, the user form do not close on pressing esc button on keybord i tried to add acode for this but didn`t work

Comment: I would suggest you create a post (question). [What is the the best way to ask follow up questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions)